# remove text from description in bulk for 2319 products

Tags: magento-1.9, category-description

I imported 2319 products from ebay to magento now i need to change the description in bulk for all the products.

for exemple in descripiton there is `<img src="http://www.dropbox.com/xxxxxxxxx">`
the xxxxxx part changed from description to description.
this is an issue because the page is not secured any more because of the link!
what can i do to fix it in bulk?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with SQL, but I recommend testing on a development environment first.

**Step 1:** find the `attribute_id` for description

```
select attribute_id from eav_attribute 
where attribute_code = 'description' 
and entity_type_id = 4;
```

**Step 2:** update all urls to have http**S** instead of http

```
update catalog_product_entity_varchar
set value = replace(value, 'http:', 'https:')
where attribute_id = 123; -- use the result from the previous query in place of 123
```